# Can an app know your location while its not on? IOS

Tags: ios, swift, background, location

I am building an app for ios that tracks your location and sends a notification when the user is in a certain area. The app works while its in the background, but is there a way that the app can track the user location and send notification  while its not even turned on?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It will help you, Read about `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Always</string>
```

Also, You can visit this links:

http://mobileoop.com/getting-location-updates-for-ios-7-and-8-when-the-app-is-killedterminatedsuspended

https://github.com/voyage11/GettingLocationWhenSuspended

**And second, Application will not show your notification if the user turns off the notification for your app in the settings. Because the notification manages by the iOS.**

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely take a look a it!! might be the awnser i was looking for :)